# How to filter by params and user input in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to display only the rows that belong to certain states in my application. I can do it the long way in Javascript, but I would prefer to better understand Rails and queries in the controller. I want to take the users to another page and then show them only that the companies in that state. It would be great to not have to link them to another page. Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is what I have in my controller

```
  def vendors
    @vendors = Collective.where(sort: 'Vendor').all
    @vendors = @vendors.where(params[:state])
  end
```

My route

```
get '/vendors/:state', to: 'collectives#vendors'
```

Then I use the stereotypical method to print a table in a html.erb file.

```
<% @vendors.each do |company| %>

<tr>
  <td><%= company.name %></td>
  <td><%= company.state %></td>
 etc...
```

Comment: For example adding a form to te page which sets session variables?

Comment: Yes, that would be the general idea if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should your controller code change the where as follows:

```
def vendors
  @vendors = Collective.where(sort: 'Vendor').all
  @vendors = @vendors.where(state: params[:state])
end
```

or better:

```
def vendors
  @vendors = Collective.where(sort: 'Vendor', state: params[:state])
end
```

Comment: I have to wait nine minutes to check mark it, but it worked!

Comment: Or you can pass it to the first where statement. `@vendors = Collective.where(sort: 'Vendor', state: params[:state])`

Answer (score 1):

**Using sessions instead of url params.**

This is more or less what you can do, sorry if it is not completly working for your case, just to give an idea.

```
# view collectives/index (or whatever you have)

<%= form_tag (controller: :collectives, action: :set_status_filter, method: :post) do %>
  <%= select_tag(:session_status_filter, options_for_select(@your_list_of_options_for_the_filter)) %>
  <%= submit_tag "Set filter" %>
<% end %>


# collectives controller

def index # or whatever, this is the page containing the form and the list to show
  @vendors = Collective.where(sort: 'Vendor').all
  if session[:session_status_filter] == # etcetera
    then @vendors = @vendors.where(state: session[:session_status_filter]) # for example
  else # another option just in case, etcetera
  end
end

def set_status_filter # this action is called by the form
  session[:session_status_filter] = params[:session_status_filter]
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to *** the view where the form is placed ***, notice: 'the filter is set to: ....' + session[:session_status_filter] } # after the session variable is set the redirects goes to index which uses the session to filter records
    end
end
```

`params[:session_status_filter]` is passed by the form to `collectives#set_status_filter`. The value is used to set the session variables. After that the action `collectives#set_status_filter` redirects to the index, or whatever page you placed the form and the list to show.

Comment: I looked into sessions but couldn't get it to work. I will try your method this afternoon and let you know if it works!

Comment: I am having a little trouble getting it to work. My control is called Collectives, but I made adjustments for it. Can you give me an example of what you would set "if session[:session_status_filter] == Whatgoeshere?" Right now I have @vendors.

Comment: @chasedougherty, edited the post, I don't know if it matches exactly your layout, but I think you can make it work. `if session[:session_status_filter]` is up to you to check if the variable is set or which value has, depending on the option list of the form. You could also use `unless session[:session_status_filter].nil?`